sample size calculation using G*Power -- which model to use based on an already calculated effect size?
I want to perform a sample size calculation using G*Power.  I have 2 predictors and want to test how these 2 predictors affect change over time in a specific cognitive measure.  The cognitive measure will be repeated 3 times.  I have 5 covariates I will be using. Based on my preliminary data, I have an effect size.  Any guidance regarding which model to use in G*Power would be greatly appreciated.

GPower (and most power analysis programs) are great, when you have relatively simple hypotheses and analysis you want to test.
When you have more complex analysis, you need to make sure that the analysis you do and the power analysis that you did are equivalent. I'm not sure what analysis you want to do. Your null hypothesis (or hypotheses) are not especially clearly stated and I'm not clear what analysis you plan to do - you say you have 5 covariates - are these measured once each or 5 times each?
This sounds like the sort of thing you would analyze using a multilevel model or a structural equation model. It's sometimes called a 'slopes as outcomes' model, because you want to see if your predictors change the slope. (That's assuming I've understood correctly).
There are many parameters that matter when you do this sort of analysis. You need to state the means of the three measures, and the standard deviations (do you expect these to be equal?), and the correlation / covariances of the three measures - will these be equal?
Will the effect of the covariates be equal for each of the measures? What is the total effect of the covariates?
When it comes to things like this, the only approach that's really going to work is simulation. You generate data under various scenarios, and then analyze it to see how often you get a statistically significant result. This also lets you see which parameters you should be concerned about, and which you don't need to be concerned about.
Another advantage of simulation is that it allows you to test your analysis techniques. Does it matter if the covariances of the three measures are not equal? Run analysis where the null hypothesis is true, and see if you get the type I error rate you expect (5%, usually). If you don't, you have other problems.
You can do this in pretty much any stats package, but you'll probably have less pain in R than anything else.

I don't think this is doable with GPower. The closest GPower model would be F-test -> ANOVA/Repeated-Measures/Within-between interaction. But that only takes one between-subject factor, no covariates and no continuous predictors in general. I recommend the Superpower software/package, see https://shiny.ieis.tue.nl/anova_power/
